# Why do programmers use %s in the print statement, instead of adding the variable, which holds a specific value(string), to the print statement?

Tags: python-3.x, string, formatting, string-formatting, operator-keyword

I don't understand why programmers use %s, when they can simply just add the variable name to the print statement. I mean its less work to type in the variable name instead of " ...%s" % name) "

Example:

```
# declaring a string variable
name = "David"
 
# append a string within a string
print("Hey, %s!" % name)`
```

Why do Programmers not type in instead:

````
# declaring a string variable
name = "David"

# printing a salutation without having to append a string within a string:
print("Hey," + " " + name + "!")`
```
````

Comment: Personally, I find the `%`-formatted version easier to read in this case, and that counts for a lot.  But I find the f-string version even easier to read (`print(f"Hey, {name}!")`), and that's generally what I would use in cases like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some performance difference, but it mostly comes down to preference.

The most modern approach is to use f-strings. With your example this would look like this:

```py
# declaring a string variable
name = "David"

# format print using f-string
print(f"Hey, {name}!")
```

This way there is no %s not is there need for all the extra + symbols and spaces.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In programming languages such as C, we use %s to use a specific string stored in a variable while printing another string,
for eg., in C language:

```c
// suppose x='John Doe'
// to print my name along with another string
printf("My name is %s", x); // Output: My name is John Doe
```

Same works in Python along with the method you specified.

There is also a method known as f-string
Eg:

```py
name="John Doe"
print(f"My name is {name}") # output: My name is John Doe
```

Another method would be .format method
Eg:

```py
name="John Doe"
print("My name is {}".format(name)) # output: My name is John Doe
```

Hope this helps